# Travelling to Portugal from South Africa via Angola

Tags: transit-visas, south-african-citizens, portuguese-citizens, angola, lad

My parents are traveling to Portugal via Angola in August.  My dad has Portuguese passport and my mom has South African passport - is a visa needed for Angola?

Answer (score 8):

In this episode of Let's Ask Timatic:

**Neither of your parents needs a transit visa**, as long as their layover in Luanda (LAD) is under 24 hours.

> [National Portugal (PT)        /Transit Angola (AO) Destination Portugal (PT)](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PT&TR=LAD&DE=LIS&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C)
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>
> [National South Africa (ZA)    /Transit Angola (AO) Destination Portugal (PT)](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=ZA&TR=LAD&DE=LIS&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C)
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

Source: TimaticWeb (links embedded in the quote)